# which Spring Batch version is recommended for production, 4.2.7 or 4.3.3?

Tags: spring-batch

we plan to use Spring Batch for mission critical production batching system. And I am wondering which version we should choose now?

From the version history in github(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tags): version 4.2.7 is marked with .RELEASE, while 4.3.3 is not.

So the questions are:

1、what's the difference regarding the versions with or without .RELEASE ending, is the ".RELEASE" ending verison more stable?

2、which version is recommended for production now ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are production ready releases, one for the 4.2 line and the other for the 4.3 line. I recommend using the latest 4.3 as it has an extended support lifetime. Spring Batch follows the same support terms as Spring Boot, and each version will be supported as long as the latest Spring Boot version that brings it is supported, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions.

For example:

- the latest Spring Boot version that brings Spring Batch 4.2 is 2.3 which will be OSS supported until May 2021.
- The latest Spring Boot version that brings Spring Batch 4.3 is 2.5 which will be OSS supported until May 2022.
- etc

Spring Boot 2.6 is expected on November 2021 and will likely bring Spring Batch 4.3 as well, which extends the OSS support for Spring Batch 4.3 for another year. So I recommend using the latest version from 4.3 to benefit from a longer support period since you are planning to use it in production. FTR, there is an ongoing effort to update the website/wiki with all these support details across the portfolio, so keep tuned.

In regard to the version name scheme, we (the Spring engineering team) have decided to switch from the old naming scheme (`.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, `.RELEASE`, etc) to a new naming scheme. This has been announced on our blog here: [Updates to Spring Versions](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/updates-to-spring-versions).

Comment: OK, got it , Thanks a lot for the answer!